# Updating value of a key in JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to change a value of only a key but as a result my whole json data is appended to old one.

Here is the script

```
import json
with open('test.json', "r+") as json_file:
        wifi = json.load(json_file)
        status = wifi["wifi_status"]
        wifi["wifi_status"] = "off"
        json.dump(wifi, json_file)
```

and this is the json file

```
{"wifi_status":"on","ssid":"my_router","pw":"my_password"}
```

and the result

```
{"wifi_status":"on","ssid":"my_router","pw":"my_password"}{"wifi_status": "off", "ssid": "my_router", "pw": "my_password"}
```

Is there a way to modify a value without dumping all information?

Comment: You are opening the file in `"r+"` mode, meaning you read from it and then write after the end. I would open in `"rt"` mode for reading and then open again in `"wt"` mode for writing.

Comment: now it works as I expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You open the file in `r+` You must open in `w` to overwrite the file

```
import json
with open('test.json', "r+") as json_file:
    wifi = json.load(json_file)
    status = wifi["wifi_status"]
    wifi["wifi_status"] = "off"

with open('test.json', "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(wifi, json_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you've opened a file and read its contents so the cursor is at the end of the file. By writing to the same file handle, you're essentially appending to the file.

```
import json
with open("x.json", "r+") as jsonFile:
    wifi = json.load(jsonFile)

wifi["wifi_status"] = "off"

with open("x.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(wifi, jsonFile)
```

Alternatively, you can use seek() to move the cursor back to the beginning of the file then start writing, followed by a truncate() to deal with the case where the new data is smaller than the previous.

Answer (score 1):

json.dumps is appending to the end of the cursor of the file pointer.

You can re-open the file with w+ to clear all the contents of the file, or you can put json_file.seek(0) before json.dumps to bring the cursor back to the start.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import json
jsonFile = open("test.json", mode="r")
jdata = json.load(jsonFile)
jdata["wifi_status"] = "off"
jsonFile.close()
jsonFile = open('test.json', mode='w+')
json.dump(jdata, jsonFile)
jsonFile.close()
```